# How to access Excel files using Microsoft office 12.0 Access Database Enginer OLEDB Provider

Tags: ssis

I wanted to load data from Excel file using Microsoft office 12.0 Access Database Enginer OLEDB Provider.

I tried using OLEDB source and changed the source provider from 
Native OLEDB\SQL Server Native Client 10.0 to Microsoft office 12.0 Access Database Enginer OLEDB Provider and am trying to access Excel file , but am not able to load Excel file data.

Thanks,

Venkat